# Inheriting with default template parameter of nested class within template outer class

Tags: class, c++11, templates, inheritance, default-value

I have a template outer class (`Outer` below) with a public template nested class (`Inner`).  The template parameter of `Inner` has a default.  I specialize `Outer` (`SpecializedOuter`), then derive from the nested class (`SpecializedOuter::Inner`) to define a new class (`SpecializedInner`).  Compilation is fine if I specify `Inner`'s template parameter in the definition of `SpecializedInner`.  However, g++ won't compile the code if I omit `Inner`'s template parameter in `SpecializedInner`, even though a default is specified (`Inner<U=void>`).

Is there any way to fix this for both g++ and VS2013?  I have looked through Google results and other questions but am having trouble getting search terms that will distinguish all of the possible uses of "default" and "template" from each other :) .

#### Code and error messages

The following `test.cpp` compiles with no errors or warnings on g++ 5.4.0, `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -c test.cpp -o test.o`:

```
template<typename T>
class Outer {
public:
  template<typename U = void>   // The default I want to take advantage of
  class Inner {
    Outer *outer_;
  public:
    Inner(Outer *outer): outer_(outer) {}
  };
}; //Outer

typedef Outer<int> SpecializedOuter;

class SpecializedInner: public SpecializedOuter::Inner<void> { 
    // also works with int or double instead of void - I just have to specify some type.
public:
  SpecializedInner(SpecializedOuter *so)
    : SpecializedOuter::Inner<void>(so)     // type also expressly specified here
  {}
};
```

However, if I remove `<void>` from `public SpecializedOuter::Inner<void>` and `: SpecializedOuter::Inner<void>`, I get compilation errors.  I would expect that the compiler would use the default `typename U = void` from the definition of `Inner`.  Code and errors are:

```
// ... definitions of Outer, Inner, SpecializedOuter as above ...
class SpecializedInner: public SpecializedOuter::Inner { // without <void> 
    // => "expected class-name before `{' token"
public:
  SpecializedInner(SpecializedOuter *so)
    : SpecializedOuter::Inner(so)     // without <void> 
    // => "expected class-name before `(' token" 
    // => "expected `{' before `(' token"
  {}
};
```

#### Use case

In case you are wondering, in my use case, `Outer` is a subclass of [OpenSceneGraph's](https://github.com/openscenegraph/openscenegraph/) `osg::Geometry` and `Inner` is a subclass of `osg::Drawable::UpdateCallback`.  I am trying to move boilerplate into `Inner` for convenience, and remove the need for a `dynamic_cast` from `osg::Geometry` to `Outer<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after posting I found the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12755947/2877364).  I'll leave it here in case it is useful for anyone else.  When using the defaults, you still have to put `<>` at the end of the class name to turn it from the name of a template into the name of an instantiated class (per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12756146/2877364) to the above question).  This compiles successfully:

```
template<typename T>
class Outer {
public:
  template<typename U = void>
  class Inner {
    Outer *outer_;
  public:
    Inner(Outer *outer): outer_(outer) {}
  };
}; //Outer

typedef Outer<int> SpecializedOuter;

class SpecializedInner: public SpecializedOuter::Inner<> { 
    // without <void>, but with <> => OK
public:
  SpecializedInner(SpecializedOuter *so)
    : Inner<>(so)     // without <void>, with <> => OK.  Plus, don't have to
  {}                  // re-specify `SpecializedOuter::`!
};
// vi: set ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 et ai: //
```